# Get file stats (size, time created ...) of hidden files with Python

Tags: python

I have problems with finding stats of hidden files with Python.
I have tried `os.stat(file)` and `os.path.getSize(file)` which is basically same command, but without success. Python keeps returning FileNotFoundError.
Excluding (skipping) hidden files is not an option, i need data for all of them.

this is code, path in my case is 'home/atana'

```
def go2path(self, path):
    file_list = []
    for i in os.listdir(path):
        print(os.path.join(path, i))
        # if i.startswith('.') is False:
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(path, i))
        file_list.append([i, a.st_size, time.ctime(a.st_atime), 
        time.ctime(a.st_ctime)]) 
    print( file_list)
```

And this is the output of function

> /home/atana/.nuget /home/atana/Videos /home/atana/.thumbnails
>   /home/atana/.python_history /home/atana/.WebStorm2018.1
>   /home/atana/packages-microsoft-prod.deb /home/atana/Downloads
>   /home/atana/Music /home/atana/.fonts /home/atana/.nv /home/atana/.java
>   /home/atana/Desktop /home/atana/examples.desktop
>   /home/atana/.wget-hsts /home/atana/Pictures /home/atana/.google-cookie
>   /home/atana/.mono /home/atana/Documents /home/atana/.steam
>   /home/atana/.dmrc /home/atana/.gconf /home/atana/.pki
>   /home/atana/.ViberPC /home/atana/.xsession-errors /home/atana/.gnupg
>   /home/atana/.npm /home/atana/.templateengine /home/atana/snap
>   /home/atana/Templates /home/atana/.designer /home/atana/.local
>   /home/atana/.steampath
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/media/atana/D:
>   150GB/programiranje/fm/main.py", line 203, in 
>       btn.clicked.connect(lambda event, path2=path: self.go2path(path2))   File "/media/atana/D: 150GB/programiranje/fm/main.py", line 215, in
>   go2path
>       a = os.stat(os.path.join(path, i)) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/atana/.steampath'

Comment: My guess is you are somehow removing/forgetting the initial `.` of the filename. You have `.hidden` but are passing `hidden` or something close. Post a small excerpt of how you are obtaining the filenames and `stat`ing them for more help.

Comment: Also, check the permission of the hidden file, it may be the case python program doesn't have sufficient permission to access the file.

Comment: I see ". steampath" is present at location /home/atana/.local /home/atana/.steampath but your script trying to access from location /home/atana/. So, I guess this is the problem.

Comment: I have found error, somehow the link was broken, so i just removed the file, and everything works fine

Comment: @VidyaSagar yes, it was some broken link to another file or something like that

Comment: I suggest you post your findings as an answer, and accept tomorrow for some rep.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just to put an answer, it seems that was broken link to another file (which was deleted or something), so after deleting it everything works fine.